# How to remove features after drawing is completed with draw interaction?

Tags: openlayers

When I finish drawing with the draw interaction, the feature is displayed on the map.

I don't want the feature to be displayed on the map.

I want to remove the feature when drawing is completed.

I removed the feature from the drawend event, but it still shows up on the map.

When should the feature be removed?

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: source,
            type: 'LineString',
            style: style,           
            freehandCondition: function freehandCondition(e) {
                return false;
            }
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

drawInteraction.on('drawend', function (e) {
    source.removeFeature(e.feature); // not work
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw features are only added if you specify a source to add them to, if you don't want to save them you don't need a source

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            type: 'LineString',
            style: style,           
            freehandCondition: function freehandCondition(e) {
                return false;
            }
});

map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with addFeature event.

```
source.on("addfeature", function(e){    
                if(e.feature == global_feature)
                {
                    source.removeFeature(e.feature);
                }                           
        });
```